# Filter out duplicated data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns ['id', 'city', 'time']:

```
   city  id       time
0   CA   1   2019-01-01 05:34:21
1   CA   1   2019-01-01 08:10:21
2   CA   1   2019-02-01 06:10:21
3   NY   1   2019-02-01 16:10:21
4   NY   1   2019-02-01 18:10:21
5   CA   1   2019-02-01 22:10:21
6   CA   1   2019-02-02 02:10:21
```

I encounter an issue that want to filter out the duplicated data according 'city' while keep the smallest 'time', like this:

```
   city   id       time
0   CA    1    2019-01-01 05:34:21
1   NY    1    2019-02-01 16:10:21
2   CA    1    2019-02-01 22:10:21
```

Due to the dataset is considerably large, it would be better not use any for loops in it. How can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df_new=df.groupby([df.city.ne(df.city.shift()).cumsum(),'city'],as_index=False).min()
print(df_new)

  city  id                 time
0   CA   1  2019-01-01 05:34:21
1   NY   1  2019-02-01 16:10:21
2   CA   1  2019-02-01 22:10:21
```

Comment: Wuh hu! That's what I was waiting for :D

Comment: @meW what exactly? :D

Comment: Got stuck in the creation of `df.city.ne(df.city.shift()).cumsum()`.

Comment: @ChrisLiu Pleasure..!! glad i could help. :)